# Date Format Changer using substring and if else statements

Tags: java

Write a program that takes as input a date in the form mm/dd/yyyy and prints out the same date in the form `dd-Month-yy`. For example, if the user inputs `5/31/2011` then the program outputs `5-May-11`

There are two challenges to this program:

- You need to read in the data and separate the parts (month, day, year)
- You need to decide which word to print – this part is the selection structure

For the first challenge, try the following algorithm:

- Read the input as a String
- Assign the substring that starts at the beginning of the String and ends with the first ‘/’ to a variable representing the month.
- Using the substring that starts after the first ‘/’ assign the substring that starts at the beginning (of the day) and ends with the second ‘/’ to a variable representing the day
- Assign the rest of the String (after the second ‘/’) to a variable representing the year

For the second challenge, you’ll use a selection structure that picks the word to print based on the value of the month variable.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String date;
        System.out.println("Please enter a date in the form mm/dd/yyyy");
        date = kb.nextLine();
        String day = date.substring(3,5);
        String month = date.substring(0,2);
        String year = date.substring(6,date.length());
        int conv = Integer.parseInt(month);
        if (conv == 1){
            System.out.println(day + "-January-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 2){
            System.out.println(day + "-February-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 3){
            System.out.println(day + "-March-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 4){
            System.out.println(day + "-April-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 5){
            System.out.println(day + "-May-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 6){
            System.out.println(day + "-June-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 7){
            System.out.println(day + "-July-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 8){
            System.out.println(day + "-August-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 9){
            System.out.println(day + "-September-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 10){
            System.out.println(day + "-October-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 11){
            System.out.println(day + "-November-" + year);
        }
        else if (conv == 12){
            System.out.println(day + "-December-" + year);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid data. try again");
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to know how can I assign a substring that starts at the beginning of the string and ends at the first "/" character.

Comment: why the `python` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int slashPos = string.indexOf("/");
String substring = string.substring(0, slashPos);
```

String#indexOf() will provide the index of the first string occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Can we use something like this :

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stringDate;
        System.out.println("Please enter a date in the form mm/dd/yyyy");
        stringDate = kb.nextLine();

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date = formatter.parse(stringDate);
            System.out.println(date);
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMMM-yyyy");
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

If there is no restriction to use SimpleDateFormat, then we can use this. Otherwise solution given by @TorchNight MC is correct.